# Cant move to next line while reading csv file

Tags: java, scala, csv

I have a class that helps me to read a csv file, and another class that creates an object of each line of the csv, so then I can run some actions for each line separately. using this for automation.

From some reason after one line my program stops...it worked before so I dont know what is wrong..

this is my csv reader class:

```
import java.io.File
import com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVReader
import jxl.{Cell, Workbook}

import scala.collection.mutable

trait DataSource {

  def read (fileName: String): Seq[Map[String, String]]
}

object CsvDataSource extends DataSource {
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.CSVFormat
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.Quoting
  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

  implicit object MyFormat extends CSVFormat {
    val delimiter: Char = '\t'
    val quoteChar: Char = '"'
    val escapeChar: Char = '"'
    val lineTerminator: String = "\r\n"
    val quoting: Quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
    val treatEmptyLineAsNil: Boolean = false
  }

  override def read(file: String): Seq[Map[String, String]] = {
    val reader = CSVReader.open(file, "UTF-16")(MyFormat)
    reader.iteratorWithHeaders.toSeq
  }
}
```

this is the PurchaseInfo class which is creating an object of each line of the csv:

```
case class PurchaseInfo(
                         something1: String,
                         something2: String,
                         something3: String,
                         something4: String) {
}


object PurchaseInfo {

    private def changeDateFormat(dateInString: String): String = {
    //System.out.println(dateInString)
    val formatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")
    val formatter2: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val date: Date = formatter.parse(dateInString)
    return formatter2.format(date).toString
  }

    def fromDataSource (ds: DataSource)(fileName: String): Seq[PurchaseInfo] = {

      ds.read(fileName).map { c =>
        PurchaseInfo(
          something1 = c("Supplier Address Street Number"),
          something2 = c("Supplier Address Route"),
          something3 = c("Supplier Address Locality"),
          something4 = c("Supplier Address Postal Code")
        )
      }
    }
}
```

Now, in the class where I perform all the actions there is one method called insertData that get a sequence of purchaseInfos and calls another method with each purchaseInfo inside this seq....

```
def insertData (purchaseInfos: Seq[PurchaseInfo]) = {

    //logging in and then getting directed to the right path (where we start the invoices automation)
    login()

    val res = purchaseInfos.map { case purchaseInfo =>
      println(purchaseInfo.invoiceNumber)
      (purchaseInfo, Try(addInvoiceFlow(purchaseInfo)))
    }
    res
  }
```

the problem is that insertData calls addInvoiceFlow only one with the first purchaseInfo and stops...why? I checked and there are 34 lines so there is no prob with the csv file..

this is written in scala but java can help too :)

Comment: You don't show how the `purchaseInfos` argument of `insertData` is constructed. Are you sure there is more than one entry in that sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you close the input file somehow before you finish reading it. I can't tell for sure because you don't provide the code that calls `insertData`. To test this hypothesis try to materialize the content of your file in `read` method by changing

```
reader.iteratorWithHeaders.toSeq
```

to

```
reader.iteratorWithHeaders.toList
```

If it will work after that, it means that you close the `CSVReader` before you consume your data.

---

Update: in my original answer I was right about the fix, but not right in my explanation. As @som-snytt correctly pointed out in his answer, `Stream.map` does not realize the stream, it merely defines an additional element transformation that should be made when a stream is actually realized. Therefore, in some case it may be useful to not realize the stream at reading point (thus creating intermediate `Map`s that are carried around), but rather do it after map, when realization will directly give you `PurchaseInfo`s, i.e.

```
ds.read(fileName).map { c => PurchaseInfo(...)}.force
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a series of `Stream.map`. The first `iterator.toSeq` is just `toStream`.

```
iteratorWithHeaders.toSeq map PurchaseInfo.apply map addInvoiceFlow
```

`insertData` will not eagerly evaluate the invocations of `addInvoiceFlow`, but only the head element.

```
scala> (1 to 10).toStream map { i => println(s"Hi, $i") ; i + 1}
Hi, 1
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)
```

So `insertData` is returning this partly evaluated stream.

You can force the evaluation:

```
scala> res0.force
Hi, 2
Hi, 3
Hi, 4
Hi, 5
Hi, 6
Hi, 7
Hi, 8
Hi, 9
Hi, 10
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
```

There's also [this issue](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv/issues/39) in case you have a parse error. See [this comment](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv/issues/39#issuecomment-107226765).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the line terminator is the sequence `\r\n`.

It could also be only `\n`.

The character `\r` is the carriage return, while `\n` is the character for new line. Windows use the couple `\r\n` for backward compabilities with dos.

Unix use only `\n`.

Comment: In general the Java IO classes to read text files don't care about the line ending.